# Adding Skype chat in e-mail signature using Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm trying to link Skypes chat link in Dreamweaver using:

skype:skype.name?chat

over the Skype icon. When I paste the html email signature in gmail, all my other links work fine except for Skype. If I open the .html file in any browser it works great. It just won't work when I see the embeded signature in gmail.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

skype:-skype-name-?chat